# What is the question actually asking?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

The question is quoted from [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/321341/27741) on math.stackexchange.com

> A cylindrical chocobar has its radius r unit and height h unit. If we wish to increase the volume by same amount either by increasing its radius alone or its height alone by the same number of units, then how many units do we have to increase the radius or height?

As you can see, the OP has proceeded to solve the question using

```
π * (r + x) * (r + x) * h = π * r * r * (h + x)
```

while, I beg to differ. In my opinion, the question seems to state that

```
π * (r + x) * (r + x) * (h + x) = 2 * π * r * r * h
```

I'm not sure though. All other users are proceeding with what the OP has put in the question.

Basically, I'm confused over the meaning of the following section of question

> volume by same amount either by increasing its radius alone or its height alone by the same number of units

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> increase the volume by same amount **either** by increasing its radius alone **or** its height alone by the same number of units

This states that the same V<sub>2</sub> is to be produced in either of two ways:

> by increasing only r by x units, OR
>   by increasing only h by x units

It looks to me like your OP got it right.

However, it would have been expressed more cleanly as

> increase the volume by **the** same amount by increasing, by the same number of units, **either** its radius alone **or** its height alone